# Application for gae does not deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I don't remember going through the process of finding a unique Application name. If that is the problem (that the name I chose was not new) can someone remind me how to start that process unless the ERROR message below is suggesting some other problem.

I am pretty sure I have not uploaded this application before, so maybe "update" is not appropriate. I clicked the "Deploy" button on my SDK window to start this process, btw.

```
*** Running appfg.py with the following flags:
    --no_cookies --email=xxx@gmail.com --passin update
Host: appengine.google.com
Application: youpoll; version: 1

Starting update of app: xxxxxxx, version: 1
Getting current resource limits.
2012-07-09 17:50:44,915 ERROR appcfg.py:2161 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Aborting. 
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u'xxxxxxx').
--- end server output ---
Password for xxx@gmail.com: If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 1 ***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique application name is selected when you create a new project on the appengine website. If you have not done that yet, go do find your application name/create your account. Also, make sure you are signed into google in Eclipse. It should say your google account name at the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 12):

I removed ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java and it solved my problem. Also, it's worth check out this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the "Registering Your Application" section in the [Getting Started guide for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading) or [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading).